# How to stop Dedicated GPU on a laptop from activating when charging?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, graphics-card, gpu, overheating

My custom laptop automatically activates the dedicated GPU when I plug it in to charge. I know this because:

- games are laggy when not plugged in as it's using integrated gpu instead.
- HWiNFO64 shows that the dedicated GPU is on low power state mode/deactivated when not charging(screenshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOA8h.png))
- when I plug it in to charge, HWiFO64 shows the GPU to be activated/boosted (screenshot [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bnqsr.png))

Is there a way to stop dedicated GPU from activating when charging? The reason is that when it activates my laptop heats up even though I put the battery saving mode (Better Battery) while charging. I know there will be an increase in temps as the battery produces heat when charging, but I dont want other components to also add more heat such as the d-gpu since I'm only using basic apps majority of the time for work.

Maybe a better question is: is there a way to manually activate the dedicated GPU when I need it, say for when I'm gaming, and just have the intigrated gpu to be the default gpu?

Also, CPU temps increases from around 40 degrees to 55/60 degrees when plugged in. I'm not sure if the CPU is also automatically 'activated' when I'm charging the laptop, or because the d-GPU is activated/boosted that the CPU therefore have to work with the d-GPU sand thus the increase of temps.